# Android SDK Manager, default browser not displaying images

Tags: android, image

I am loading my web pages into the default browser in the Android Emulator using Xampp and localhost (as 10.0.2.2). The pages load okay but no images are displayed.

In browser settings, under bandwidth management, ‘Load Images is ticked’. Google displays images if I do an image search.

Turning off anti virus and firewall makes no difference.

Appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others experiencing this issue, in my case the problem was due to the following line of code in .htaccess intended to prevent hotlinking of images:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?mydomain.com [NC]
```

I had created a further rule so that the images were available on my localhost as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://localhost/etc [NC]
```

But I had not created a rule for port 10.0.2.2 that the Android Emulator was running on.